# JScrollPane touch scrolling doesn't work in IE10/Surface

Tags: touch, jscrollpane, internet-explorer-10, jquery-jscrollpane

I've tried searching for this but it doesn't appear to be a known issue.

Finger scrolling doesn't appear to work in IE10, even on the main jscrollpane site: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Demos: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

Only tested on a Surface RT device...

It seems to work fine on iOS/Android devices.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft Surface: How do I allow JavaScript touch/drag events to work without being intercepted by the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130004/microsoft-surface-how-do-i-allow-javascript-touch-drag-events-to-work-without-b)

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue, I have found the following article somewhat helpful, but still can't seem to get it to work completely. I would have just commented but I don't have enough rep apparently.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772044(v=vs.85).aspx

From what I can tell, this has something to do with IE10 and 11 hijacking the touch action on touch devices in order to allow the user to swipe left and right to switch between apps. I am currently testing on a Surface Pro2 using both the metro version of IE11 and the desktop version of IE11. According to the article you should be able to prevent that behavior using css "touch-action" property but I can't quite get it to work right. I'll update if I find anything more useful.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to get this to successfully work well. The surface never seemed to respond to my statements to prevent the hijacking. Basically, it looks like it's a battle between the jquery scrollpane and the surface fighting for control. The solution we came up with was to ditch jscrollpane and use standard scrolling divs with css3 scrollbar styling. Best solution thus far.