# MS Surface tablet IE10 with Highcharts scroll page issue

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10, highcharts

I am having some issues with Highcharts in Surface tablet. My problem is as follows:

The chart works perfect in iOS, and Android devices (tablets), but in Surface when I tapped in the chart and start moving right or left so I see the tooltip, the browser tries to scroll the page instead. I can only tapped but again the tooltip appears and disappears immediately.

I read that Surface + W8 uses a different approach to handle touch events with the concept of MSPointers.

Has anyone experienced the same behaviour using Highcharts with Surface tablet? If so, will be much appreciated if you shed some light how to achieve this.

Thanks,

-Martin

Comment: Have you tried with IE10 on different hardware? Do you have an example that illustrates the issue?

Comment: hi rowland. i finally managed to fix this issue by simply adding -ms-touch-action:none. weird i tried this before i posted this and no success. I think, this option was added in the wrong div element. This issues is now fixed. Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft Surface: How do I allow JavaScript touch/drag events to work without being intercepted by the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130004/microsoft-surface-how-do-i-allow-javascript-touch-drag-events-to-work-without-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to fix this issue by simply adding -ms-touch-action:none. Need to make sure to add this in the correct element.